# How to remove this space in proof environment?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, environments

When a proof ends with a math equation, it adds an extra space. It means that the proof square goes to the next line and doesn't appear exactly in the last line.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
...
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \Longrightarrow & B\\
 & \Longrightarrow & C
\end{array}$$
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

And the compiled result is the following.

[image]

What should I do to have the square exactly aligned, it means in the same line "\Longrightarrow C" exists?

Comment: the `ntheorem` package does what you want automatically, at least for an equation on a single line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never (in the sense of ***never ever***) use `$$...$$` in LaTeX. For no reason whatsoever. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

For proofs that end with a display there is `\qedhere`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{align*}
A & \Longrightarrow B\\
 & \Longrightarrow C\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the nature of the alignment, you can also use

```
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
A & \Longrightarrow B\\
 & \Longrightarrow C\qedhere
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}
```

Comment: What is difference between align and split?

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh Several, but explaining them is quite long. You can look at the documentation of `amsmath` for more information. I don't know what's the right environment to use in your case because the formulas are too generic.

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum, you should (a) insert the directive `\qedhere` immediately after "`C`" and (b) change `\begin{array}{ccc}` to `\begin{array}[b]{ccc}`. The `[b]` ("bottom") positioning specifier informs LaTeX that the QED symbol should be aligned at the bottom rather than at the center of the `array`.

Incidentally, you should *not* use `$$` to initiate and terminate displaymath-mode in a LaTeX document. It's badly deprecated. Instead, use `\[` and `\]`. See [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for a longer discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point that `ntheorem` has an automatic placement of the end-of-proof symbol, without having to ask it (`thmmarks` option). In addition, we can use its `amsthm` compatibility option:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref, amsthm]{ntheorem}%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
...
 \begin{align*}
A & \Longrightarrow B\\
 & \Longrightarrow C
\end{align*} %
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]